# Perl - CodeGolf - Nested loops & SQL inserts

Tags: perl, performance, foreach, code-golf, nested-loops

I had to make a really small and simple script that would fill a table with string values according to these criteria:

- 2 characters long
- 1st character is always numeric (0-9)
- 2nd character is (0-9) but also includes "X"
- Values need to be inserted into a table on a database

The program would execute:

```
insert into table (code) values ('01');
insert into table (code) values ('02');
insert into table (code) values ('03');
insert into table (code) values ('04');
insert into table (code) values ('05');
insert into table (code) values ('06');
insert into table (code) values ('07');
insert into table (code) values ('08');
insert into table (code) values ('09');
insert into table (code) values ('0X');
```

And so on, until the total 110 values were inserted.

My code (just to accomplish it, not to minimize and make efficient) was:

```
use strict;
use DBI;
my ($db1,$sql,$sth,%dbattr);
%dbattr=(ChopBlanks => 1,RaiseError => 0);
$db1=DBI->connect('DBI:mysql:','','',\%dbattr);
my @code;
for(0..9)
{
    $code[0]=$_;
    for(0..9)
    {
        $code[1]=$_;
        insert(@code);
    }
    insert($code[0],"X");
}
sub insert
{
    my $skip=0;
    foreach(@_)
    {
        if($skip==0)
        {
            $sql="insert into table (code) values ('".$_[0].$_[1]."');"; 
            $sth=$db1->prepare($sql); 
            $sth->execute();
            $skip++;
        }
        else
        {
            $skip--;
        }
    }
}
exit;
```

I'm just interested to see a really succinct & precise version of this logic.

Comment: Perl, Ruby, Python and PHP - the only languages suitable for golf with databases... it's not enough... too specific theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### 133 characters - non-strict

```
use DBI;$d=DBI->connect('DBI:mysql','','',{RaiseError=>1});for$a(0..9){for$b(0..9,'X'){$d->do("insert into table values('$a$b')");}}
```

#### 152 characters - strict

```
use strict;use DBI;my$d=DBI->connect('DBI:mysql','','',{RaiseError=>1});for my$a(0..9){for my$b(0..9,'X'){$d->do("insert into table values('$a$b')");}}
```

#### Legible version of 152 character string:

```
use strict;use DBI;
my $d=DBI->connect('DBI:Informix:stores','','',{RaiseError=>1});
foreach my $a (0..9)
{
    foreach my $b (0..9, 'X')
    {
        $d->do("insert into table values('$a$b')");
    }
}
```

#### Thought process

Given:

```
create table table(code char(2) not null);
```

And the Perl:

```
use strict;
use DBI;
my $d=DBI->connect('DBI:mysql','','',{RaiseError=>1});
my $h=$d->prepare("insert into table(code)values(?)");
foreach my $a (0..9)
{
    foreach my $b (0..9, 'X')
    {
        $h->execute("$a$b");
    }
}
```

I tested with Informix, so the connect string I actually used was "`DBI:Informix:stores`".

This solution is still readable - and because of the RaiseError, error-proofed (unless you want to add a transaction too).

Code Golfing it, it becomes (182 characters):

```
use strict;use DBI;my$d=DBI->connect('DBI:mysql','','',{RaiseError=>1});my$h=$d->prepare("insert into table(code)values(?)");for my$a(0..9){for my$b(0..9,'X'){$h->execute("$a$b");}}
```

Comment: i've been so used to adding the strict that i don't even stop to ask why. - so... what's it for (in a nutshell)?

Comment: `use strict;` is used by experts to make sure they aren't making a silly mistake; `use strict;` is ignored by beginners because they don't realize it will stop them making mistakes.  But when you're code golfing, every byte counts, so `use strict;` is antithetical to 'Code Golf'; so are multi-character names.  That has to be close to minimal; there are 6 necessary spaces in the strict version (4 in the non-strict).  The attribute hash could be omitted in the connect; that would save some more space (16 bytes, I believe), but I don't like dropping all error detection.

Comment: silly mistakes like "missing a semicolon at line 7" or using one "=" equal sign in an if comparison?

Comment: Yes, like those - or typos in variable names, or many others.  Actually, some of them are handled by `use warnings;` rather than `use strict;` and the latter is more about abusing strings as references...

Comment: @JL - yeah i noticed you dropped some of the db connect attribs too.  if im not mistaken, you could also drop the quotes around the execute param vars and throw a comma in there

Comment: @CheeseConQueso: no, I don't think you can drop the quotes around the execute parameters - though the most compressed code doesn't even use the execute, of course.

Comment: @JL - yeah, i've had a couple beers and tried to correct YOU?  stupid....  esp since i always ask for your help   btw - its xmas eve @8pm and were on SO.  at least i have more beer.... time to go for now

Answer (score 1):

The first part can be reduced to

```
for my $x (0..9) {
  for my $y (0..9,'X') {
    insert("$x$y");
  }
}
```

I really don't understand what $skip is doing in the second part. I'd have

```
sub insert {
  my $code = shift;
  my $sql="insert into table (code) values ('$code');"; 
  my $sth=$db1->prepare($sql); 
  $sth->execute();
}
```

Comment: without the skip, each line would print twice

Comment: oh, and thanks for the first part - i never knew you could construct for statements like that

Comment: It only prints twice when you use `foreach(@_)` over a two-element array. By avoiding that, you also avoid the need for `$skip`;

Answer (score 1):

You could just do it in sql (for some values of sql):

```
insert into table (code) select concat(foo, bar)
from (select 0 foo union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4
    union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9)
    foo
join (select 0 bar union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4
    union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9
    union select 'X')
    bar;
```

Comment: this is nice - never expected this to make it happen